# Как поменять цвет checkbox?

Tags: android, checkbox, android-xml, android-themes

Как изменить цвет всего `Сheckbox` с того, что по умолчанию, на свой? То есть должен получится и `Сheckbox`, и текст возле него одного цвета.

Как поменять цвет текста я знаю, а вот чтобы и квадратик с флажком поменяли свой цвет, не нашел. Пробовал через стили, но тоже без результата. Нужно, чтобы цвет неотмеченного квадратика `Сheckbox` был одним, а при клике менялся на другой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

переопредели цвета для состояния чекбокса:

```
Checkbox checkbox = findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
int states[][] = {{android.R.attr.state_checked}, {}};
int colors[] = {R.color.color_checked, R.color.color_unchecked};
CompoundButtonCompat.setButtonTintList(checkbox, new ColorStateList(states, colors));
```

Answer (score 2):

используйте AppCompatCheckBox и AppCompatRadioButton вместо CheckBox и RadioButton.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
    android:id="@+id/cbSelected"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent" //This to set your default button color
    android:checked="true"/>

<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
    android:id="@+id/rb"
    app:buttonTint="@color/colorAccent" //This to set your default button color
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Java код : Создайте ColorStateList

```
   ColorStateList colorStateList = new ColorStateList(
            new int[][]{
                    new int[]{android.R.attr.state_enabled} //enabled
            },
            new int[] {getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary) }
    );
```

Поменяйте программно цвет для AppCompatRadioButton или AppCompatCheckBox вызвав setSupportButtonTintList.

```
AppCompatRadioButton radioButton = (AppCompatRadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rb);
radioButton.setSupportButtonTintList(colorStateList);

AppCompatCheckBox cbSelected = (AppCompatCheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cbSelected);
cbSelected.setSupportButtonTintList(colorStateList);
```

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38565260/5330439)

Answer (score 1):

Ты можешь создать свой drawable, и потом добавить в хмл чекбокса

`android:drawableStart="@drawable/your_check_drawable"
android:button="@android:color/transparent"`

Или создай совой selector и 2мя вариантами drawable для разных стейтов и в drawableStart (к примеру) тогда уже selector добавляй.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5854047/how-to-change-the-color-of-a-checkbox

Comment: а где мне цвет прописывать в drawable я насколько вижу по примерам то цвет там нигде не указывается, даже если мы потом его подключаем к style.xml